# How will I able to insert span value to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, database, drop-down-menu, html

I can't seem to find the right solution to insert my span values into the database. Or are there any other options on how to show values from the database by selecting from the dropdown list? Here is my code.

Here is my javascript getting the values being selected from the drop down list.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showUser(userNumber, str) 
{ 

if (str=="") 
{ 
  document.getElementById("value" + userNumber).innerHTML=""; 
  return; 
}   
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} 

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
{ 
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
  { 
    //document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var coron = responseText;
    var meas = "";
    var unit ="";

    if (responseText.indexOf("NOT A VALID") == -1)
    {
      coron = responseText.substring(12, responseText.indexOf(",Value:")); 
      meas = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Value:")+7,      responseText.indexOf(",Weight:")); 
      unit = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Weight:")+8);

    }

    document.getElementById("value" + userNumber).innerHTML = coron;
    document.getElementById("meas" + userNumber).innerHTML = meas; 
    document.getElementById("unit" + userNumber).innerHTML = unit;
  } 
} 
xmlhttp.open("GET","coron.php?q="+str,true); 
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Here is my form.

```
<form name="mainform" method="post" action="submit.php">
<table align = "center" border = "1" ><tr align = "center"><td class = "laman">Qty.
    <td class = "laman">Units
    <td class = "description">Desciprtion of Articles
    <td class = "laman">Value
    <td class = "laman">Meas/Weight
    <td class = "laman">Freight Charge</tr>
    <tr align = "center"><td class = "laman"><input size = "5" type = "text" name = "qty" onkeyup = "calculateTotal()" />
    <td class = "laman"><span id="unit1"></span>
    <td class = "description"><? 
                                $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
                                mysql_select_db("ler_marineland", $con) or die(mysql_error());

                                $sql="SELECT product_id, description FROM product"; 
                                $result=mysql_query($sql); 

                                $options=""; 


                                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

                                    $product_id=$row["product_id"]; 
                                    $description=$row["description"]; 
                                    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$product_id\">".$description.'</option>'; 

                                } 
                                ?> 

                                <SELECT id=myselect onchange="showUser(1, this.value);"> 
                                <OPTION VALUE=0>
                                <?=$options?>
                                </SELECT>

    <td class = "laman"><span id="value1" name="value"></span>
    <td class = "laman"><span id="meas1" name="meas"></span>
    <td class = "laman"><span id="fc" name="fc"></span></tr>
            <tr><td>Voyage No. <td><input size = "8" type = "text" name = "voyage_no" />
```

PHP

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ler_marineland", $con) or die(mysql_error());


            $qty= $_POST['qty'];
            $units= $_POST['units'];
            $description= $_POST['description'];
            $value= $_POST['value'];
            $meas= $_POST['meas'];
            $fcharge= $_POST['fc'];
                            $voyage_no= $_POST['voyage_no'];


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM coron WHERE voyage_no = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($voyage_no).'"'; 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO coron (voyage_no, qty, units, description, value, meas, fc) VALUES ('$voyage_no', '$qty', '$units', '$description', '$value', '$meas', '$fc')") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is what I'm trying to do, select an item from a populated drop down menu then after selecting, it will show its corresponding value, measurement and unit automatically. I find code that fits my project then came up with that javascript code. And found out that the code displays only using span or div. But supposedly, I really want to display it into a textbox. Now, I want to store them by submitting it into the database but I can't seem to know how. Are there any other ways to get the corresponding values, measurement and unit automaticcaly by selecting from a drop down list? Please help me out. I am really new to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: *sidenote:* suggest to use jQuery to reduce your hassle on XHR; your JS code looks clumsy.

Comment: The input field values are posted not span's value. You use jquery: `$( "value1" ).val();`

Comment: What am I going to do? I really don't know how since I'm new to this.

Comment: @Marianne Why are you using `<span>` for values to be entered in your DB, why not use checkboxes, radio buttons, or inputs instead? Plus, why get into something so complex if you're new to this?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, select an item from a populated drop down menu then after selecting, it will show its corresponding value, measurement and unit automatically. I find code that fits my project then came up with that javascript code. And found out that the code displays using span or div only. But supposedly, I really want to display it into a textbox. Now, I want to store them by submitting it into the database but I can't seem to know how.

Comment: use input type hidden, save the span value in it.

Comment: I've already tried that but it's not working :(

Comment: @Marianne I understand. I have seen questions here on a similar subject, and to tell you quite frankly, I don't know how to do it, however it does have something to do with echoing the `row` from within the `<select>` in conjunction with the DB. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: @Marianne A question just came up which could be of interest to you and looks like what I mentioned to you earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841374/create-dropdownlist-from-value-in-database-php