# Create dropdownlist from value in database php

Tags: php, forms, oracle, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to display a list of name (from oracle db) that user can choose as their supervisor at my form.

This code below only display one letter from the first name in db.
eg: The first name in db is 'nanie', but it display 'n' only.

Please help me to correct this code.

```
    <?php 
    $sql3= oci_parse($conn,"SELECT stfname FROM staff") or die ('None'); 
    $result3=oci_execute($sql3); 
    $row3 = oci_fetch_array($sql3,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);  
    echo $row3['STFNAME'];
    ?>

    <td><strong>Co-supervisor : </strong></td>
    <td width="309">
        <?php echo '<select name="cosupervisor">'; 
            foreach($row3 as $value)
        {
              echo '<option value="'.$value['STFNAME'].'">'.$value['STFNAME'].'</option>';                          } 
        echo '</select>'; ?>
    </td>
```

Comment: Use while loop here for fetching data from database.

Comment: In query you are using small letters in field name "SELECT stfname FROM staff" but after fetching in array you used capital letter $row3['STFNAME'].

Comment: for select statement it is not case-sensitive. But for fetching array, "Oracle's default, non-case sensitive column names will have uppercase associative indices in the result array." Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreach loop through while as:
**Co-supervisor :**

```
    <?php 
    echo '<select name="cosupervisor">'; 
      while($row3 = oci_fetch_array($sql3,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
    {
        $data[] = $row3 ;                         
    } 

     foreach($data as $value)
        {
              echo '<option value="'.$value['STFNAME'].'">'.$value['STFNAME'].'</option>';                          } 
        echo '</select>'; ?>
    </td> 

   ?>
</td>
```

Comment: It works! :) Thanks @Dk-Macadamia. But can u explain, why we need to use both foreach and while? and why u fetch $row3 using $data[]?

Answer (score 0):

use `while` instead of `foreach` loop

```
<?php 
$sql3= oci_parse($conn,"SELECT stfname FROM staff") or die ('None'); 
$result3=oci_execute($sql3); 
//$row3 = oci_fetch_array($sql3,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS);  
//echo $row3['STFNAME'];
?>

<td><strong>Co-supervisor : </strong></td>
<td width="309">
    <?php 
    echo '<select name="cosupervisor">'; 
      while($row3 = oci_fetch_array($sql3,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row3['stfname'].'">'.$row3['stfname'].'</option>';                          
    } 

    echo '</select>'; 

   ?>
</td>
```

Comment: I've try. It works. I can see there is a list (option works) but unable to display the value.

Comment: @naniel, ohh, one more change `$row3['stfname']` instead of `$value['stfname']` :)

Comment: It works! Yeay. Thanks. But, instead of using $row3['stfname'], I change to $row3['STFNAME']. If not, it will unable to fetch.